# Count elements not containing certain class

Tags: jquery

How can I count elements .em that do not have section with class .extra?

```js
var cnt = $('.em').not('.extra').length;
console.log(cnt);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="em">
  <div class="header">aaa</div>
  <ul>nnn</ul>
</div>

<div class="em">
  <div class="header">aaa</div>
  <div class="extra">eee</div>
  <ul>nnn</ul>
</div>

<div class="em">
  <div class="header">aaa</div>
  <ul>nnn</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were negating `.em` elements with a class of `.extra`. Since none of the `.em` elements have the class `.extra`, all of them were selected.

One option would be to combine [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) with the [`:has()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/): `.em:not(:has(.extra))`

```js
var cnt = $('.em:not(:has(.extra))').length;
console.log(cnt);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="em">
  <div class="header">aaa</div>
  <ul>nnn</ul>
</div>

<div class="em">
  <div class="header">aaa</div>
  <div class="extra">eee</div>
  <ul>nnn</ul>
</div>

<div class="em">
  <div class="header">aaa</div>
  <ul>nnn</ul>
</div>
```